# How to .exe file to msi via jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to .net application (non-web application) project and using jenkins for continuous build and release. I completed creating builds for my project and got the .exe and dll files. But i need to repackage it(create a msi) before deploying to servers. So can anyone give a stepwise information for rePackaging and tool to be used with jenkins for packaging. I want to automate this process in jenkins CI AND CD.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is not capable to pack any applications directly.

It will always use an external tool via a plugin or installed by you.
In MSI case, you need an windows agent with an app that will receive the command in command line and produce your deliverable.

Applications:

- [Installshield](https://info.revenera.com/is-eval-installshield-professional?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=installshield&utm_matchtype=e&utm_campaign=EN-SWI-IS-EMEA-Brand-SMART&utm_content=IS_EVAL_IS&k_clickid=_k_Cj0KCQjwjPaCBhDkARIsAISZN7QYV4TgIDcxgVhSJonNmIiTYeqb6aR01ctsd56gtPCiZnBOTV-CQ8oaAtqzEALw_wcB_k_&id=ProEdition_EVAL_2011&lead_source=PPC&gclid=Cj0KCQjwjPaCBhDkARIsAISZN7QYV4TgIDcxgVhSJonNmIiTYeqb6aR01ctsd56gtPCiZnBOTV-CQ8oaAtqzEALw_wcB) (very old - paid)
- visual studio (paid)
- TFS (on premises or cloud) (paid)
- [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/overview) (? I don't know much about it)
- [WIX](https://wixtoolset.org/) (free)

Jenkins plugin [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/advanced-installer-msi-builder/)

Comment: thanks for your reply buddy, have you tired with WIX ??

Comment: which tool is best one buddy? - Iftimie Tudor

Comment: No, it's been years since I've stopped building .net stuff. In order to get more advice form the community, I recommend you to update your question with details like : framework used & versions, do you need a step by step installer or just a msi that will do unattended installation, targeted windows platforms for the installer you create. Also you can add for some more  meaningfull tags . I replied just from jenkins point of view (the only tag atm)